# Select Distinct Query Left JOIN, Still getting duplicates in my result

Tags: oracle

I am writing a select query with distinct but I am still getting duplicates in my result. The Oracle View do have duplicates and I am trying to get back only 1 occurrence of that value.

Here is my query

```
select
person.person_id,
person.last_name,
person.first_name, 
person.first_name,
person.middle_name,
skill.skills_id,
(case
when trim(skills.skill_description) = 'typing fast' then 'TP1'
when trim(skills.skill_description) = 'courier district 9' then 'CD9'
when trim(skills.skill_description) = 'helpdesk shift 3' then 'HD3'
when trim(skills.skill_description) = 'helpdesk shift 5' then 'HD5'
....
else ''
end) AS skill_description
from person_view person
left join (select distinct person_id, skill_id, skill_description, updated_date
from skill_view) skills
on skills.person_id = person.person_id and
((trunc(sysdate) - PHONE.UPDATED_DT <= 1))  and
trim(skills.skill_description) in ('skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3' ...)
```

There is a lot of values for skill_description, so I add the IN clause to filter for 15 - 20 specific skill_description values.

My case will take a the value and set the code for it.

I thought when I used the 'distinct' keyword it would filter out the duplicates but it is not working.

Here is my output so far

```
105 John E Doe SKILL1

105 John E Doe SKILL1

105 John E Doe SKILL2

105 John E Doe SKILL2

105 John E Doe SKILL3

105 John E Doe SKILL3
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Huh?  You just edited to add something about a PHONE.UPDATED_DT, but there is no mention of the PHONE table in your query. What's up with that? Please make sure whatever you post COMPILES WITHOUT ERRORS before you ask questions about it not returning the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `DISTINCT` is in an inner level and maybe the duplicates are outside the `LEFT JOIN`, you must put the `DISTINCT` clause in the first `SELECT`.

This should give you the desire output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       person.person_id,
       person.last_name,
       person.first_name,
       person.first_name,
       person.middle_name,
       skill.skills_id,
OMMITED CODE...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `updated_date` in the subquery, but you don't use it in the outer query. QUESTION: Why? Did you mean to use it for something, perhaps to only select the most current info from the table?

In any case, if you have the same `person_id`, `skill_id` and `skill_description` values but different `updated_date`, `DISTINCT` won't help; the rows may very well be distinct in the inner query, but cease to be distinct in the outer query (if you don't include `updated_date` in the projection).